# There are just too many for me!

Tags: riddle

> You can mix *me* up, but that is not *my* goal.
>   You can find *me* in my recent past.
>   The fans disgust the most famous of them all.

---

This is my first riddle, so no idea how easy or hard it will be (came up with it while cycling home). I also came up with five hints, so if the correct answer isn't posted by tomorrow, I will spoil the hints one by one every ± 12 hours.

Hint:

> There is a difference between the same regular font and *italic* font words, they are not the same.

Comment: Is the title there as a hint?

Comment: I guess the third clue corresponds to >! Justin Bieber...

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Spoilers do not work in comments.

Comment: You should reveal the hints bit by bit rather than all at once, as the aim is more to lead people in the correct direction and give them time to come to a conclusion without overwhelming them with extraneous (and spoilery) information.

Comment: @feelinferrety You're indeed right, so I've added the first hint. I'll try to add a hint like once every ± 12 hours. _@RichardRoe_ was **very** close to the correct answer though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you are

> Twisty Puzzle

Hint 1:

> I guess that the roman font refers to the author of the puzzle and italic font to the solution of the riddle.

You can mix *me* up, but that is not *my* goal.

> The goal of twisty puzzles is to set them in order but you have to mix them up before you start.

You can find *me* in my recent past.

> In the authors past posts he was asking what is the name about a particular twisty puzzle.

The fans disgust the most famous of them all.

> The most famous is the Rubik's cube. But I don't know about this clue, maybe because it hard to solve?

Title:

> From the authors profile it can be seen that he collects these puzzles. and there are too many puzzles for the author to collect them all.

Comment: All correct, except for a halve :) "**The most famous is the Rubik's cube.** But the cubing community (a.k.a. fans) will never recommend it because of the bad turning quality compared to modern days speed-cubes." [Here is an example of how the cubing community thinks about a Rubik's brand. :)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/comments/4ak85l/rubiks_cube_getting_smashed_with_a_100_ton_press/)

Comment: Ha, didn't know about that :)

Answer (score 10):

A guess:

Is it

> A Rubik's cube?

You can mix me up but that is not my goal

> You can mix a cube up, but the goal is to "unmix" it (order it correctly)

You can find me in my recent past

> A previous arrangement of the cube can be found by undoing recent moves

The fans disgust the most famous of them all

> Not sure. Perhaps it is disgusting how hard it is?

Additionally:

> The title might refer to the 43,252,003,274,489,856,000 possible combinations.

And:

> Your profile pic has a Rubik's cube in it

Comment: Very, very close, +1 But for the word I was looking for (or actually two words), you'll have to think more in general. (2 out of your 6 answers in spoiler-tags are correct.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> pathogens

You can mix me up, but that is not my goal.

> The goal of pathogens is to infect

You can find me in my recent past.

> Pathogens mutate very quickly when placed in a different environment but you can still look at the ones that haven't mutated

The fans disgust the most famous of them all.

> The most disruptive pathogens are famous (superbugs)